Who is the rightful owner of stolen property?
Our mother is 100 years old and has been declared incapacitated due to dementia.
In 1969, when I was 15 and my brother was 17, our Mom instructed us to go to her mother's home and steal an item that she dearly wanted, to remove it without our grandmother's consent or knowledge.
Our mother still has possession of the item.  Mom's mother and 3 siblings are deceased.
How should we deal with this item, procured illicitly, when we are dealing with her personal belongings?  There is no mention of this item in Mom's trust, will, or personal papers.
I feel a strong duty to make sure this is handled correctly as I have carried the burden of the crime with me since I was a teenager.  I was unable to resolve conflicting 4th and 7th commandments in my 15 yo brain.
My 5 siblings think the item should remain with my mother's branch of the family.  I think it should be shared with all 4 branches of my grandmother's descendants (my mother's descendants plus the descendants of her 3 siblings).
What is the right thing to do?

Law.SE can't tell you what the "right thing to do" is. We can tell you what the law is. The statute of limitations for a larceny that occurred in 1969 expired long ago, and your mom obtained ownership by adverse possession, and by your grandmother's estate's failure to claim it, long ago. Estate plans rarely mention particular items of property.

Also, per the usual, the law is different in different places. There isn't a universal rule of law that applies everywhere in the world.

It sounds like your conscience is telling you what the "right thing to do" is. Go with it. If you're looking for more confirmation, [interpersonal.se] is a good place to ask about intrafamily issues like this.

I'm also curious what kind of item could realistically be shared by all her descendants. Is it a painting that could be passed from home to home for periods of time?

The stolen item is a dollhouse-size wooden house with yard, fence, furnishings and accessories, all handmade by Mom's father, a carpenter.  It was made to be displayed under the Christmas tree.

It’s your mother’s
or not - depends where you are and facts not in evidence.
The general rule is that title does not pass to a thief and a thief cannot pass title on to a subsequent possessor. In the circumstances you describe, the most reasonable interpretation is that you and your brother committed larceny and your mother was an accomplice. That means, at the time of the theft, it was still legally the property of your grandmother.
However, in every common law jurisdiction, there are statute of limitations within which an action must be brought or the former owner loses their right to the object. The justification for this is that a diligent owner should be pro-active in protecting their interests and that without such limitations the courts would be dealing with claims of theft going back, potentially, for centuries.
The typical period for these is 6 years, however, there is considerable variation on when this time starts to run:

From the theft
From when a diligent owner knew or should have known the object was stolen (e.g. Australia)
From the time it passes to a possessor in good faith (i.e. not the thief or anyone that knows it’s stolen), they can always sue the thief or a possessor in bad faith (e.g. UK)
From when a diligent owner should have discovered the location of the object (e.g. most US states)
From when the actual location is discovered (e.g. some US states inc. California)
From demand and refusal (e.g. some US states inc. New York)

So, whether your mother can be disposed of it or not depends on where the theft occurred and what interactions happened between your grandmother and your mother over the object.
Of course, knowing who legally owns it doesn’t answer the question of what you should do about it. That’s an ethical question, not a legal one.

To clarify, are you referring to a statute of limitations that would apply to the criminal acts involved in the actions? Or are you also including a SOL for bringing a civil case? If the latter are you suggesting that when the civil SOL expires that the thief has obtained the title effectively by adverse possession?

@Pyrotechnical the second. Whether title passes after that depends on the jurisdiction, in some it does, in others it stays with the original owner but they are unable to recover the object through the courts despite owning it.
